# C++ Segfault and I dont know why?

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I declared an array in my header file like this:

```
private:
   int frames[10];
```

And assigned values in the class constructor like so:

```
file.open(File);
if(file.is_open())
{
    std::string line;
    getline(file, line);
    std::string param[10];
    std::stringstream stream(line);
    int n=0;
    while(!stream.eof())
    {
        getline(stream, param[n], '$');
        frames[n] = atoi(param[n].c_str());
        n++;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Later on this array is used in a function:

```
currentFrame++;
if(frames[currentAnimation] <= currentFrame)
{
    currentFrame = 0;
}
```

When I run I run my code I get segmentation error, and gdb returns this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000402c22 in Sprite::update (this=0x7ffff6efe678 <main_arena+88>) at Sprite.cpp:93 93              
if(frames[currentAnimation] <= currentFrame)
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000402c22 in Sprite::update (this=0x7ffff6efe678 <main_arena+88>) at Sprite.cpp:93
#1  0x0000000000401fcb in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffeb88) at main.cpp:146
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, I think the error is somewhere here.
I can't really post all of the code as its a lot but if you need anymore
specific information please just ask.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: How do you make sure `n < 10` or `currentAnimation < 10`? Most likely you are invoking undefined behavior by accessing out of bounds.

Comment: I guess frames[currentAnimation] referres something outside the array

Comment: have you tried printing out the index you use?

Comment: I would check the value of `currentAnimation` in the `if` statement.

Comment: What's the content of frames[] after reading in the values? What is the value of currentFrame when it crashed?

Comment: Why are you using plain c-style arrays instead of `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: Your code is not exception-safe; if an exception gets thrown before `file.close()`, you’re screwed. Use RAII.

Comment: I am sure currentAnimationand n are in bounds, I checked before. I don't know what RAII is, I will try to use vectors instead. Thanks all

Comment: If you are sure that currentAnimation is in bounds then you would still get the crash if you used if(currentAnimation < 10 && frames[currentAnimation] <= currentFrame). If you do not get the crash then currentAnimation was out of bounds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
private:
   std::vector<int> frames;


file.open(File);
if(file.is_open())
{
    std::string line;
    getline(file, line);
    std::string param;
    std::stringstream stream(line);
    while(getline(stream, param, '$'))
        frames.push_back(atoi(param.c_str()));
    file.close();
}

currentFrame++;
if( currentAnimation < frames.size() && frames[currentAnimation] <= currentFrame)
{
    currentFrame = 0;
}
```

[See Loki's answer for why while(!stream.eof()) is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19683759/259)

Comment: Thank you this worked, but still dont understand why mine does not.

Comment: @user2936306: Because your code assumed there were only 10 input items (thus `param[n]` and `frames[n]` failed when n>=10). This code has no limitation on the input size.

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
int n=0;
while(!stream.eof() && n < 10)
{
```

...

and

```
currentFrame++;
if(currentFrame < 10 && frames[currentAnimation] <= currentFrame)
{
    currentFrame = 0;
}
```

or use something like

```
currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues:

You only have 10 items here:

```
std::string param[10];
```

But there is no check here for 10:

```
while(!stream.eof())
```

So this may add more than 10 which will certainly cause problems.

Also this form of loop is almost always wrong:

```
while(!stream.eof())
{
    getline(stream, param[n], '$');
    frames[n] = atoi(param[n].c_str());
    n++;
}
```

If you have any bad data in your input this will go into an infinite loop. Otherwise when you reach EOF the `std::getline()` fails to read data and sets the eof flag but you still assign to frames (and increment n). `atoi()` on bad data returns 0 so the last element in `Frames` will be zero (not sure if this is intended behavior or not (but its sloppy).

The correct style is to put the read into the while condition. So adding these two things together you loop should look like this.

```
while(n < 10 && getline(stream, param[n], '$'))
{
    // loop is only entered if the read succeed.

    // Not sure about the type of `frames` so hard to talk about
    // if this loop is still correct. The meaning has changed slightly.
    frames[n] = atoi(param[n].c_str());
    n++;
}
if (n < 10) {/*We have an issue with not enough data!*/}
```